# Split string in equal chunks in Lua

Tags: string, lua

I need to split a string in equal sized chunks (where the last chunk can be smaller, if the strings length can't be divided without remainder).

Let's say I have a string with 2000 chars. I want to split this string in equal sized chunks of 500 chars, so I would end up with 4 strings of 500 chars.

How can this be done in Lua, when neither the length of the initial string is fixed, nor the chunk size?

**Example**

String: "0123456789" (Length = 10) should be splitted in strings of 3 characters

Result: "012", "345", "678", "9"

(doesn't matter if the result is in a table or returned by a iterator)

Comment: `s = "0123456789"; k = 3; t = {s:match(('('..('.?'):rep(k)..')'):rep(math.ceil(#s/k)))}`

Comment: Presumably, by "chunks," you mean characters, [or is it graphemes](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html)? A Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes. In general, you can't know the number of bytes in a character or grapheme without inspecting each one so division doesn't always make sense. Which character set and encoding are you using? One with exactly one byte per character (e.g., Windows-1252)? Exactly 4 bytes per character (e.g., UTF-32)? One to four bytes (UTF-8) or two or four bytes (UTF-16)? A character set with combining characters (Unicode) or without (Windows-1252)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To split a string into 4, you can get the size like this:

```
local str = "0123456789" 
local sz = math.ceil(str:len() / 4)
```

Then the first string is `str:sub(1, sz)`, I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 7):

```
local function splitByChunk(text, chunkSize)
    local s = {}
    for i=1, #text, chunkSize do
        s[#s+1] = text:sub(i,i+chunkSize - 1)
    end
    return s
end

-- usage example
local st = splitByChunk("0123456789",3)
for i,v in ipairs(st) do
   print(i, v)
end

-- outputs
-- 1    012
-- 2    345
-- 3    678
-- 4    9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> function tt(s)
>>     local t={}
>>     for p in s:gmatch("..?.?") do
>>         t[#t+1]=p
>>     end
>>
>>     for i,v in ipairs(t) do
>>         print(i, v)
>>     end
>> end
> tt("0123")
1       012
2       3
> tt("0123456789")
1       012
2       345
3       678
4       9
> tt("012345678901")
1       012
2       345
3       678
4       901
```